# MarkerSize relative to plot window size

Tags: matlab, plot

In a figure, I plot with this command:

```
plot(x, y, 'sr', 'markersize', 20)
```

When I resize the plot window, the markers don't resize as well. What is the command to make the marker size relative to the window size?

Answer (score 2):

To precisely control how a figure behaves when you resize it, you can define a window resize callback function by setting the figure's `ResizeFcn` property.  There's more information [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure_props.html).

Comment: I'm more looking for a solution similar to this : `set(gca,'DataAspectRatio',[1 1 1])`